# How to get system theme in Rust?

Tags: rust, themes, system

Some systems allow users to define a theme like "light" or "dark" as default and many apps use this to set its initial color scheme. In a rust application is there a way to find current theme? There might be a way with the Windows API but I am looking for a better solution that might include any operating system with a defined theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing like this in the standard library. I found this crate: [dark-light](https://crates.io/crates/dark-light), but I haven't tested it, so use at your own risk. If you're using a GUI library, it likely has this functionality built-in.